# Can batch file input password automatically to cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, runas

I often use "msra offerra/" command to connect my user's desktop. To do so, **I have to use different username and password than my current windows session**. What I usually do is,

win button + R (to open Run)
then

```
runas /user:domainname\username cmd
```

after that, cmder (terminal) asks me the password for following user. I input my password and only after that I use this command

```
msra /offerra
```

And it opens the window I need.

**Here is my question:**

Can I somehow automate this procedure with one batch file? When I click on that .bat it opens runas..., input my given password and then gives msra offerra/ command?

Answer (score 1):

Just write the commands in your batch file as you would do in your cmd, adding an auto-input of your password:

```
@echo off
echo PASSWORD| runas /user:domainname\username cmd
msra /offerra
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad! Thanks @Stephan

Comment: Thanks Rasgel. I tried it, however didn’t work. Even tho I’m sure the login name and password is correct, it gives me an error - “Login Failure. Username or Password wrong” and opens the Remote Access window with my present Windows session’s credentials. when I do it manually password works perfectly.